# Chromecast Launch, what's with the DIAL parameters? Aren't I runing MY application, not some registered standard?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

The following code displays a proper list of available chromecast devices on my network.  But when I click on the links, the application never launches.   There are a couple of things that I'm quite confused about that may or may not be related to this question:

1. If I'm making my own custom application, what's with the DIAL parameters and why do I have to pass them?  I don't want to write an app for the DIAL standard... this is MY app.
2. Again related to the DIAL parameters, if I search for devices with any other query other than "YouTube" (a DIAL parameter), the list always comes up blank.  I suppose I shouldn't care, as long as the device is listed... but again... the app won't launch.

It should be noted that my sender app is a chrome webpage.

I'm a bit confused as to where my "appid" goes int he launch parameters,'

```
    <html data-cast-api-enabled="true">
    <body>
    hi!<BR/>

    <script>
    var cast_api, cv_activity;

    if (window.cast && window.cast.isAvailable) {
      // Cast is known to be available
      initializeApi();

    } else {
      // Wait for API to post a message to us
      window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        if (event.source == window && event.data && 
            event.data.source == "CastApi" &&
            event.data.event == "Hello")
        {
              //document.write("Initialize via message.<br/>");
            initializeApi();
              //document.write("Api initialized via message.");
        };
      });
    };

    initializeApi = function() {
      cast_api = new cast.Api();
      cast_api.addReceiverListener("YouTube", onReceiverList);
    };

    var g_list;
    onReceiverList = function(list) {
        g_list = list;
    // If the list is non-empty, show a widget with
    // the friendly names of receivers.
    // When a receiver is picked, invoke doLaunch with the receiver.
    document.write("Receivers: "+list.length+"<br/>");
    var t;
    for(t=0;t<list.length;t++)
      document.write('found:<a href="javascript:launchy('+t+')">'+list[t].name+'</a> ' +list[t].id+'<br/>');
    };

    onLaunch = function(activity) {
      if (activity.status == "running") {
        cv_activity = activity;
        // update UI to reflect that the receiver has received the
        // launch command and should start video playback.
      } else if (activity.status == "error") {
        cv_activity = null;
      }
    };

    function launchy(idx)
    {
      doLaunch(g_list[idx]);
    }
    doLaunch = function(receiver) {
      var request = new window.cast.LaunchRequest(">>>>>what REALLY goes here?<<<<<<< ", receiver);
      request.parameters = "v=abcdefg";

      request.description = new window.cast.LaunchDescription();
      request.description.text = "My Cat Video";
      request.description.url = "http://my.website.get.your.own/chomecast/test.php";
      cast_api.launch(request, onLaunch);
    };

    stopPlayback = function() {
      if (cv_activity) {
        cast_api.stopActivity(cv_activity.activityId);
      }
    };

    </script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

The part marked "what really goes here?" is the part that I THINK is wrong... I couldn't be completely wrong.   My device is white listed, I have an appid (which I thought might go in that slot)... The documentation merely says ActivityType DIAL Parmeters are valid, mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the LaunchRequest is your App ID, the one that you have received in an email as part of whitelisting process. Also, the "YouTube" in the initialize method should also be replaced with the same App ID.

I strongly suggest you look at the sample that is on GitHub for chrome sender to see how you can send a request to load a media on a cast device.

Comment: thanks... yes... the GIT example works just perfect!